# How to add a separate column to data frame with lubridate? Would like to have numerical month and word month in the data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, lubridate

The lubridate allows us to break down y-m-d format to month, year week, etc... I have done this with my data set. I have the months in numerical months, but want a separate column with month abbreviations. I can convert them, but I want to have both numerical and word month in the data frame. Is there another way to go about doing this besides manually adding a column vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lubridate::month` generates the numerical month. Adding the argument `label = TRUE` generates the month abbreviation. You can use `dplyr::mutate` to add the new column.

For example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data.frame(Date = as_date("2001-10-11")) %>% 
  mutate(Month = month(Date), 
         MonthAbb = month(Date, label = TRUE))

        Date Month MonthAbb
1 2001-10-11    10      Oct
```

Comment: Good! Please accept the answer if it solves the problem.